# taylor series with bounded derivatives.

Tags: calculus

given f(x) derivable infinite times, and exists L such that $|f^{(n)}(x)|\le L$  for $x\in\Bbb R$ and $n \in \Bbb N$, prove that if $f({1 \over n})=0 ~(n \in \Bbb N)$  than f(x)=0 $(x \in \Bbb R)$

the hint in the question's body suggest to show that for every $k \ge 0$ exists a sequence such that $a_n \to 0$ and $f^{(k)}(a_n) = 0$ for any $n \in \Bbb N$. that i managed to prove easily with induction.

my solution

i tried to use the fact that if exists L such that $$|f^{(n)}(x)|\le L$$ than $$R_n(x) \le L \cdot {|x-a|^{n+1} \over (n+1)!} \to 0$$

also:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n {f^{(k)}(x_0) \over k!} (x-x_0)^k + {f^{(k+1)}(c) \over (k+1)!} (x-x_0)^{(k+1)}$$

but the series is for a given point, not a sequence... can't just stick $a_n$ instead of $x_0$.

Comment: You have (more or less) proved your series is convergent to $f(x)$, for all $x$. Take $x_0=0$, then using continuity, prove $f(0)=0$. How can you then prove that each $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ ? (hint: still using continuity at $0$)

Comment: great help. thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using majoraion of the rest of the Taylor series, you prove $R_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ for all $x$, thus

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$

Since $f$ is continuous, from $f(1/n)=0$ you deduce $f(0)=0$.

Now, let $k$ be the smallest integer such that $f^{(k)}(0) \neq 0$. Then, on a small enough interval $]-\epsilon, \epsilon[$ with $\epsilon>0$, your function is nonzero except at $x=0$, because it's close to $\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$ (you can write this more formally).

It's a contradiction, since for all large enough $m$, you have $1/m \in ]-\epsilon, \epsilon[$, thus your function has infinitely many zeros in this interval. So there is no such $k$, and $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$.